# Angularjs code not working with Django

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates, django-views

I want to add simple angularjs code to django. For this I have taken the simple example:
I have put the below code in my template:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.firstName = "John";
                $scope.lastName = "Doe";
        });
</script>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

        First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
        Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
        Full name:{{firstName}}

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My view.py is as follows:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
        template = loader.get_template('warlist/index.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render())
```

Now when I run it,it is taking the names in the text feild but It is not printing the full name.
However same angularjs code is working fine without django.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are using Django template engine to render `firstName`. But it is not passed through your `view` and, thus, it's not recognized by Angular. To "escape" `{{ }}` characters and use Angular's, do this:

```
Full name: {% verbatim %}{{firstName}}{% endverbatim %}
```

That way Django will not try to parse `{{ }}` and instead Angular's `{{ }}` will be used. Check [`verbatim`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) for details.

Comment: Great man..It is working.How to transfer the value of the firstName and lastName in views.py. Any clue?I want to parse the text that user has entered in the text section.

Comment: For that, it is better to ask a different question. That's how SO works. No sub-questions in comments. However, in a nutshell, you would create a form (which will include the `<input>` tags) and make a `POST` request to Django. Your view then will receive the values of the `<input>`s and handle them approprietly.

Answer (score 2):

Django templates use the same interpolation than angular, which is double brackets `{{}}`. You can use `$interpolateProvider` in your config method to change angular notation, so it doesn't collide with Django templates.

```
module
  .('myApp')
  .config(function($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('{$');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('$}');
})
```

Then anytime you need to interpolate anything in your view:

`Fullname: {$ firstName + lastName $}`